# Getting 500 (Internal Server Error) while insert data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, bluehost

I have successfully inserted data using the `save()` function Laravel using xampp local server. But while I tried to insert data from live server `bluehost` it gives error

```
GET http://sencare.com.bd/sencare.com.bd/confirm_appointment?patient_name=sabbir&patient_number=01654&patient_email=rahmanarafat13%40gmail.com&patient_age=2&patient_gender=1&service_id=1&schedule_time_id=1&date=+2018-03-19 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):2069
dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
```

Controller code

```
$data = new Appointment;

$data->patient_name = $request->patient_name;
$data->patient_number = $request->patient_number;

$data->save();
$lastInsertedId = $data->id;

    if($lastInsertedId > 0)
    {
        $service_name = Service::find($request->service_id);
        $schedule_time = ScheduleTime::find($request->schedule_time_id);
        $schedule_date = Appointment::find($lastInsertedId);

        $emailDataArray = array(
            'patient_name' => $request->patient_name,
            'patient_number' => $request->patient_number,
            'patient_email' => $request->patient_email,
            'patient_age' => $request->patient_age,
            'schedule_date' => $schedule_date->schedule_date,
            'schedule_time' => $schedule_time->schedule_time,
            'service_name' => $service_name->name
        );
        $this->sendMail($emailDataArray);
        // return $schedule_date->schedule_date;
        // return $emailDataArray['patient_email'];
        return $lastInsertedId;
    }


    return 0;
```

Here `Appointment` is the model where table `appointments` included and in that table I want to insert data.

Where is the problem anyone help please ?

Comment: There's a `;` missing at the end of the third line of code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware...sorry it's missing here mistakenly...not in the code

Comment: And can you show the full description of the error? Or can you show the log file?

Comment: what is the error log says?

Comment: try `new Appointment();`

and whats happening after you save();

whats the code.

Comment: I have updated my question....please check

Comment: @Jigs1212..not working brother

Comment: try returning 0 before if.
and check is it working

Comment: ya it's working....but in local server not in live srever

Comment: check ur errorlog and tell us the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167160/discussion-between-jigs1212-and-raff).